# Сделать универсальный метод из нескольких похожих

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, инспекция-кода

Можно ли из таких методов сделать один универсальный?

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateDoc_IndexItem([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
{
    return this.Ok(this._documentQueries.UpdateItem(deserialize<doc_Index>(jsonData)));
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateDoc_MarketingItem([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
{
    return this.Ok(this._documentQueries.UpdateItem(deserialize<doc_Marketing>(jsonData)));
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateDoc_CostItem([FromBody] dynamic jsonData)
{
    return this.Ok(this._documentQueries.UpdateItem(deserialize<doc_Cost>(jsonData)));
}

private JsonSerializerSettings setJsonSettings()
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    };

    settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        //DateTimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
        DateTimeFormat = "dd.MM.yyyyTHH:mm"
    });
    return settings;
}

private T deserialize<T>(dynamic jsonData)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData.ToString(), setJsonSettings());
}

public bool UpdateDoc_IndexItem(doc_Index doc)
{
    var res = this.Connection.Update(doc);
    return res;
}

public bool UpdateItem(doc_Index doc)
{
    var res = this.Connection.Update(doc);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Они по сути отличаются только классом, строковое имя класса могу присылать в параметре jsonData, но тогда как его потом превратить в класс?

Comment: что за функция _deserialize_?

Comment: string className = jsonData.className.ToString()

Comment: private T deserialize<T>(dynamic jsonData)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonData.ToString(), setJsonSettings());
        }

Comment: отредактировать вопрос, добавив в него необходимую информацию можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: У тебя три реализации _UpdateItem_?

Comment: Да, я использую для Update таблиц БД Dapper.Contrib

Comment: Вот его синтаксис: T Get<T>(id);
IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>();
int Insert<T>(T obj);
int Insert<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Update<T>(T obj);
bool Update<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool Delete<T>(T obj);
bool Delete<T>(Enumerable<T> list);
bool DeleteAll<T>();

Comment: превратить имя класса из json в тип можно банальным оператором `switch`, который заодно проверить разрешенные имена.

Comment: либо какой-нибдуь `Type.GetType` но с проверкой имен разрешенных классов. Но имхо прямой `switch` предпочитительнйе, поскольку позволит еще не передавать прям корректные имена классов, а может задать их как-то иначе